# Apollo Server health check not getting called

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo-server, nodejs-server

This is a basic issue which I followed the documentation and it is not working as expected, please shed some light.

So, I am creating a grapqhl server with **Apollo-Server** and trying to get the health-check url working that is given here `https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/features/health-checks`

Here is the code:

```
const { ApolloServer, makeExecutableSchema } = require('apollo-server')

const typeDefs = require('./schema/types/')
const resolvers = require('./schema/resolvers/')
const schema = makeExecutableSchema({ typeDefs, resolvers })
const server = new ApolloServer({
  schema,
  onHealthCheck: () => new Promise((resolve) => { console.log('hc called'); resolve() })
})
server
  .listen({ port: 5000 })
  .then(({ url }) => console.log(`  Server ready at ${url}`))
  .catch(() => console.log('error'))
```

As I start the server I get this log:

```
  Server ready at http://localhost:5000/
```

And also, I am able to see the Schema in **graphql-playground** as well, which means my **typeDefs** and **resolvers** are fine, but when I ping the url:

`{server_address}:5000/.well-known/apollo/server-health`

I am getting the output as:

```
{
   "status": "pass"
}
```

Without any log saying: **hc called** which I added in the code for key named '**onHealthCheck**' and for now I resolved it as well, as per the docs.

So where is the problem and what I missed, please shed some light.
Happy coding :)

PS: I am using **apollo-server 2.5.0** version which I think very recently updated with onHealthCheck fix for [onHealthCheck not getting called](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/issues/1449)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix was just merged into master 6 days ago. You need to update to a later version, like `2.6.0-alpha.8`.

Comment: Thanks.. it worked, but just as a doubt can't we change the response to other json?